# How can I allow special characters for a username?

Tags: php, validation, special-characters

Is there any way to allow characters such as "-" and "." (underscore and full-stop) in a username? Right now I'm using the `ctype_alnum()` function, but I don't know how to let the user use "." and "-".

```
if (ctype_alnum($uid) == false) {
      $uidERR = "Only letters and numbers are allowed";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```php
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/', $uid)) {
    $uidERR = "Only letters and numbers are allowed";
}
```

This will match all uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, `.`, `_`, and `-`.

Comment: sorry to ask, but is there anyway you could upvote my post, I just need it for a badge thanks :)

Comment: No problem! If that solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct so that future users can see that this is a valid solution.

Comment: thank you, will do. it just says I have to wait 2 mins until I can mark it as correct